# How to create circle and set image like screencast, I have used TintImage for this

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Hi I am working in shoping app and design like, I have already used tint image:

How I can do that, I I can create a circel like this image [image]

Comment: TintImage Code: <controls:TintedImage x:Name="tintedImage" Source="MenClothing.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="45" WidthRequest="45" HorizontalOptions="Center" Aspect="AspectFill"/>

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are not using icons from the resources or get the images from rest api.

This is only needed if you want to create dynamic icons.

If that is the case, use a Frame and put the image on it.

```
<Frame  CornerRadius="15" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="120, 10, 30, 30" Padding="5" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand"  HasShadow= "false" BackgroundColor="red" >
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                        <Label Text="1" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />                                           
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
```

the important thing to note is that , "cornerRadius" should be help the size of "AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds" width and size.

to learn more about AbsoluteLayout go [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout)

Comment: I have used this code but image is not fit. If I give HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40"  then image size increase.

Comment: what do you mean by not fit?
can you share the code with us?

Comment: <Frame  CornerRadius="28" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="120, 10, 30, 30" Padding="5" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand"  HasShadow= "false" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" >
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">                                    <controls:TintedImage x:Name="tintedLuggage" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" Source="Luggage.png" VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="Center" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
 </StackLayout>          </Frame>

Comment: you used the same AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds as me "120,10,30,30"

Those should be different according to your needs. Read about Absolute layout on the link on my answer.

set the size of the image on the bounds and the corner size should be half the size.

Also, you need to use <AbsoluteLayout></AbsoluteLayout>
and put the frame inside it. I am not sure if you did that or not

Comment: the padding will be the distance from the image to the circle.
If you can share where you put this frame and a screenshot, it will be clear for me. 

I will try to create a simple example for your if I have time.

Answer (score 0):

Use **FFImageLoading** NuGet Library in your Solution, you can download using link [FFImageLoading](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading/)

**Paste Below Code**

```
 <ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"
            DownsampleToViewSize="true"
            Source = "http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.jpg">
            <ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
                <fftransformations:RoundedTransformation Radius="50"/>
            </ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
 </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```